# How to deploy a vanilla web project (html, css, js) in netlify?

Tags: netlify

I'm trying to deploy a project from a Github repository to netlify, the project is organized as follows:

```
assets/
    - imgs/
    - scripts.js
    - styles.css

screens/
    - home.html
    - about.html
    - projects.html
    - contact.html
```

When I deploy the site from a repository, in the **Publish directory** section, I enter the name of the **screens** folder, which is where I have the `.html` files.

In the case of the `home.html` file I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="../assets/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

However, at the end of the deploy configuration, which is just what I said before, I enter the site and I cannot see the styles or the scripts that I have implemented, however, if I open my project on a localhost, both the styles and the scripts can be seen.

I have been moving the folders, changing the file routings, and what I have seen so far is that it only works as long as all the files are in the same folder, that is:

```
page/
    - img1.png
    - img2.png
    - img3.png
    - scripts.js
    - styles.css
    - home.html
    - about.html
    - projects.html
    - contact.html
```

Which is very disorganized and obviously not even a good practice for file distribution, so I would like to know if there is something I need to configure in the deploy so that I can obtain the assets (.js and .css) and the folder imgs (all the files in that folder) without having to be in the same directory